How can I measure Monte Carlo convergence in distribution with heavy tails?
I'm performing a Monte Carlo study on a simple agent based simulation, and I'm trying to formulate a heuristic for the number of MC samples to use. I'm able to measure convergence of statistics like mean and variance by looking at the variance of the Bootstrapped estimates.
The issue that I'm running into is that I believe my output distribution has heavy tails, and I want to be sure that I'm accurately estimating the probability of extreme risk scenarios (low probability, high consequence).
Is there a way to apply Bootstrapping to extreme quantiles? Are there any pitfalls I should watch out for?
Edit: I should add that I don't know a priori whether my output distribution is heavy-tailed or not. I'm looking for a way to quantify the confidence that I've correctly captured the behavior in the tails.

Did you consider https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelman-Rubin_statistic

This would be like simulating quantiles for the Cauchy distribution, for which each random variate is the ratio of two random standard normal variates (i.e., $X=N(0,1)/N(0,1)$).   The outliers can be very sparse and very large (negative & positive tails), with little correlation between simulated distributions.  What comes to mind to tone this down (via data transformation) is some type of truncation operation like -$\log(\textrm{abs}(x))$ for negative and $\log(X)$ for positive, or clipping 5% of values in upper/lower tails.

If you want to simulate preferentailly from the tail, maybe exponential tilting can help?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341704/simulation-of-a-random-variable-given-the-moment-generating-function-after-expon

Is there a way to apply Bootstrapping to extreme quantiles? If you bootstrap extreme values you may not use vanilla bootstrap but m out of n bootstrap

As @kjetilbhalvorsen pointed out, a safe strategy is to simulate from another distribution, with thicker tails, in order for importance sampling weights to remain bounded and the resulting estimators to enjoy a finite variance. See e.g. Radford Neal's highly popular blog post "The Harmonic Mean of the Likelihood: Worst Monte Carlo Method Ever" on the dangers of an infinite variance Monte Carlo estimator.

@Xi'an, the issue with importance sampling and exponential tilting is that I don't know the form of my output distribution. I'm doing a forward UQ study by way of Monte Carlo. Maybe there's something I'm missing with these methods, but I don't think I could apply them here.
